# gitlabe cicd : get to know if branch or tag

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm aware of for instance `-only` that let us running jobs on specific branch or tag.
I'm just wondering whether one can do similar thing with predefined environment variables only.
Well, it's just a matter of curiosity than a real need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `only:variables:`/`except:variables:` or you can use `rules:`

```yaml
myjob:
  # ...
  only:
    variables:
      - $FOO == "bar"
```

or with `rules:`

```yaml
myjob:
  rules:
    - if: '$FOO == "bar"'
```

You can use most of the [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for use in `rules:` or `only:variables`/`except:variables:`.

You can use variables like `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` or `CI_COMMIT_TAG` to control when a job runs for particular branches/tags.

Comment: Thank you, all my apologies for the delay